# PostgreSQL 9.3 Uninstall error - Windows 2012

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, windows-server-2012

I am trying to uninstall PostgreSQL 9.3 from a Windows 2012 server using the **uninstall-postgresql.exe**. During the uninstall, I get an error:

***The uninstall-postgresql.dat file cannot be found and is required to uninstall the application, aborting. Uninstallation did not complete successfully***

The uninstall-postgresql.dat exists. Not sure if its corrupt or something.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error message and still use the **uninstall-postgresql.exe** to uninstall the DB from the Windows system?

Comment: I got the same problem with PostgreSQL 10. I also ran the uninstaller from the command line and even provided the uninstall.dat file path as an argument but nothing changed the error message uninstall.dat file not found. Path in PG10 is installation-directory\uninstall\uninstall.exe and the uninstall.dat file is in the same directory.